Delete data in Adonis.Js
I have a function in the controller to delete a registered user, but I receive this error:

Erro ao deletar usuário: Exception: Row not found
at ModelQueryBuilder.firstOrFail (file:///C:/sistema/node_modules/@adonisjs/lucid/build/src/orm/query_builder/index.js:370:19)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at ChatsController.deleteEquipe (C:\sistema\app\controllers\chats_controller.ts:326:18)
update app/controllers/chats_controller.ts

This is my code:
@inject()
  async deleteEquipe(ctx: HttpContext) {
    try {
      await ctx.bouncer.with('UserPolicy').allows('adminCobranca')
      const user = await ChatUser.findOrFail(ctx.params.id)
      if (ctx.auth.user!.departamentoId === user.departamentoId) await user.delete()
      else throw new Error('Usuario nao pertence ao departamento')
      handleSuccess(ctx, 'Sucesso ao deletar')
    } catch (error) {
      handleError(ctx, 'Erro ao deletar', error)
    }
  }

I need delete an user without an error

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The error is pretty clear.  It can't find a row in your database with key matching whatever value ctx.params.id is.  Without debugging details, it's impossible to answer how you should resolve this error.  Obvious first questions would be: what value is ctx.params.id?  Does a row with this key exist in ChatUser's table? You need to verify these things before asking others for help and provide us these details.
